# count number of items in xml with php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, count

I have to parse xml files  that look like this : http://goo.gl/QQirq

How can I count number of items/records in this xml- by 'item' I mean a 'productItem' element, ie there are 5 items in the example xml. I don't specify the tag name 'productItem' when parsing the xml, so I can't count occurrences of 'productItem'. Here is the code I have:

```
        <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("test.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc );
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//*| //@*' );
$nodeNames = array();
foreach( $nodes as $node )
{
    $nodeNames = $node->nodeName;
    $name=$node->nodeName;
    $value=$node->nodeValue;
    echo ''.$name.':'.$value.'<br>';
    }

?>
```

How can I count number of items and display them one by one, like this ideally : http://goo.gl/O1FI8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName?

```
//get the number of product items
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('productitem')->length;
 //traverse the collection of productitem
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('productitem') as $element){
  //$element is a DOMElement
  $nodeNames = $element->nodeName;
  $name=$element->nodeName;
  $value=$element->nodeValue;
  echo ''.$name.':'.$value.'<br>';
}
```

As you want to traverse your document, use XPath is just greedy. Moreover you will instantiate each node of the document even if you only want one or two.

You can use hasChildNodes methode and childNodes attribute to traverse your document

```
function searchInNode(DOMNode $node){

     if(isGoodNode($node)){//if your node is good according to your database
         mapTheNode($node);
     }
     if($node->hasChildNodes()){
         foreach($node->childNodes as $nodes){
             searchInNode($nodes);
         }
     }
}
searchInNode($domdocument);
```

Comment: I have xml feeds from many merchants/platforms, and don't want to hard code it and end up with a parser for each merchant/platform. I need to fetch the file and choose which fields I want to map. it's a kind of "generic" parser.

Comment: The problem is that your "generic parser" is in fact a list of each node in the document. FOr now there is no criteria on which I can rely to help you. You say you don't know nodenames, so what is you criteria to know which node you will map?

Comment: yes, it is a list of each node in the document. In the first place, I want to display all nodes to see which ones contain the information I need, and then match them with the fields I have in my DB. My question is: is there a way to determine that 'productItem' elements are the "items" I am looking for without specifying the tagname?

Comment: Ok. If you just want to traverse the Document You can use SimpleXmlIterator http://php.net/manual/fr/class.simplexmliterator.php or the hasChildNodes() method and childNodes attribute. I edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i have found a script that does approx what I need. Your function will however help when mapping each node.